# wcf restful service method invoke error for http post

Tags: wcf, rest, http-post, webrequest, wcf-rest

I have a simple restful wcf service which I have created just for fun. I tried the invoke the post method but I am failling. here is the summary;

this is my service contract interface;

```
namespace WcfServiceWithNortwind.Smooth {

    [ ServiceContract]
    public interface INorthwindService {

        [ WebGet (UriTemplate = "/" )]
        [ OperationContract ]
        List <Category2 > GetCategories();

        [ WebGet (UriTemplate = "categories/{id}" )]
        [ OperationContract ]
        Category2 GetCategory(string id);

        [ WebInvoke (UriTemplate = "categories/{id}" , Method = "DELETE")]
        [ OperationContract ]
        void DeleteCategory(string id);

        [ WebInvoke (UriTemplate = "categories" , Method = "POST")]
        void AddCategory(Category2 category);

    }
}
```

this is the data members of my service which is Category2 Class;

```
namespace WcfServiceWithNortwind.Smooth {

    [ DataContract]
    public class Category2 {

        [ DataMember ]
        public int CategoryID { get; set ; }

        [ DataMember ]
        public string CategoryName { get; set ; }

        [ DataMember ]
        public string Description { get; set ; }

    }
}
```

this is the code which I am trying to invoke the post method;

```
    System.Xml. XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml. XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(context.Server.MapPath( "~/@xml/category.xml" ));

    string strHostAddress = "http://localhost:54860/Smooth/Nortwind.svc/categories" ;

    string xmldata = doc.OuterXml;
    string _data = String .Format( "{0}{1}", "category=" , xmldata);

    WebRequest _WebRequest = WebRequest .Create(strHostAddress);
    _WebRequest.Method = "POST" ;

    byte [] byteArray = Encoding .UTF8.GetBytes(_data);
    _WebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ;
    _WebRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

    Stream dataStream = _WebRequest.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();

    var _response = _WebRequest.GetResponse();
```

and this is the xml file that I am using to send which is category.xml;

```
<? xml version =" 1.0 "?>
<Category2>
  <CategoryID />
  <CategoryName> Tugberk's Category </CategoryName>
  <Description> .net, wcf, wpf, mvc, silverlight </Description>
</Category2>
```

when I run the code, I am getting the following error as soon as I try to _WebRequest.GetResponse() call;

> The incoming message has an
>   unexpected message format 'Raw'.  The
>   expected message formats for the
>   operation are 'Xml'; 'Json'.  This can
>   be because a WebContentTypeMapper has
>   not been configured on the binding. 
>   See the documentation of
>   WebContentTypeMapper for more details.

I also tried to post it with fiddler with request builder function of it and I got the same error as well.

So what I am missing here guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the header Content-Type: application/xml in your request and either set a namespace on your XML payload *or* remove the Namespace from your DataContract. Like [DataContract(Namespace="")]

Comment: I think that the problem is related to namespace as well. I haven't had time to try it but I will today. thanks !

Comment: Can we see the solution of what did have in the end to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Change the request's content type to `text/xml; charset=utf-8`

Comment: I did that with *application/xml; charset=utf-8* and as you indicated with *text/xml;charset=utf-8*. Now I am getting this exception; There was an error checking start element of object of type WcfServiceWithNortwind.Smooth.Category2. The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.